# Gradle sync failed , and gray files

Tags: android, gradle

Good day,

I tried to install android studio many times on my Mac but SDK not complete install and all files appears with gray really, I reset my Mac and reinstall android studio agin but the same problem generate.. 
 there is problem with gradle sync failed .
Please help me I didn't find solution. 
[this is screen shot for problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Rk0.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the menu bar, go to `Tools` > `SDK Manager` > go to `SDK Tools` tab > check if `Android SDK Built-Tools` has status as installed. In your case, it might not be installed, so try installing from there.

Comment: I check its status installed

Comment: Also check the status of 'Android SDK Platform-Tools' in the same tab.

Comment: Also, it has been installed